# How do I reference a line of code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reference

I’m trying to teach myself JavaScript.
I want to be able to reference a line of code so the system can identify it and register it.

```
console.log(a * w_discount - a * tax - a)
```

How do I link the answer of this up to do further coding with it?

Comment: Assign the result of the expression to a variable? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: The same way you created `a`, `tax`, and `w_discount`

Comment: [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: @Wally it would help us all a lot if you clarified your question a bit: what do you mean by "the answer" (the result of `console.log` or the argument statement) and where do you want to link it exactly? What should be the result, what do you want to achieve by "linking"? Do you maybe have an example in another programming language maybe?

Answer (score 0):

try use following code which write stack-trace on console (but look on chrome console not snippet) (you can also use `error` instead `warn`)

```
console.warn('xx');
```

```js
function test() {
    console.warn('xx');
}

test();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question. Then again, the question is not really clear. Didn't downvote your answer however, that was someone else :P

Comment: @Cherusker I only guess that may be this is what OP really looking for - but it is blind shot

Answer (score 0):

Store the expression in a variable as such:

```
var x_variable = (a * w_discount - a * tax - a)
```

Then reference it anywhere else.

```
console.log(x_variable)
```

You can name the variable anything you want.

Comment: I am not sure if `let` is the way to go if you walk your first steps in JS land.

Comment: The earlier the better, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe, but I would at least add the disclaimer `var` vs. `let`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/